# OpenOrd Gephi Layout

Tags: gephi

The OpenOrd layout plug-in for Gephi provides a layout algorithm called OpenOrd. That layout appears to work differently than the other layout algorithms. Alas, Javadocs seem to be missing. Here's code (in Scala) that works beautifully for the ForceAtlas2 layout using Gephi Toolkit:

```
val layout = new ForceAtlas2(new ForceAtlas2Builder)
layout.setGraphModel(myGraphModel)
layout.initAlgo
```

...

All of the other layouts work equally well with analogous code. Here's the code (in Scala) I've got for OpenOrd:

```
val layout = new OpenOrdLayout(new OpenOrdLayoutBuilder)
layout.setGraphModel(myGraphModel)
layout.initAlgo
```

It looks the same, but initAlgo throws a NullPointerException every time. Has anyone gotten OpenOrd to work? If so, what three lines do I replace these with?

Answer (score 2):

I was running into the same issue and after grabbing and stepping through the [source](https://github.com/gephi/gephi-plugins/blob/openord-layout/OpenOrdLayout/src/org/gephi/layout/plugin/openord/OpenOrdLayout.java#L98), I noticed that "param" field was the cause of the NullPointerException.

You just need to call resetPropertiesValues before initAlgo.

```
layout.setGraphModel(graphModel);
layout.resetPropertiesValues();
layout.initAlgo();
```